# jquery - on click of menu item or another element will change body background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read many tutorials and can't seem to get it right. Ok I know that the jquery click function works when you are doing something to the exact same element but how do you make it effect another and toggle back?

I have a menu and when I click on an item I want the background (body) to change to an image.

Example: 
HTML

```
<body>
<ul class="menu"> 
  <li class="menu-item"><a>item 1</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a>item 2</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a>item 3</a></li>

</ul>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".menu-item a").click(function () {
  $(body).css('background', 'http://example.com/image.png'); <-- first menu item
  $(body).css('background', 'http://example.com/image.png'); <-- second menu item
  $(body).css('background', 'http://example.com/image.png'); <-- third menu item
   });
```

Comment: that's not valid JS.  Hard to tell what you're doing here.  Is this pseudo code? `== first menu item` is obviously not valid, and you still have some PHP in there that does some generating of the JS (e.g. the `echo`)  Can you please clean this up?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to change background image based on wich <a> element is clicked? What's that " echo' "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.index()` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGFzJ/)

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var i = $("li").index( $(this).parent() );

  if ( i === 1 ) {
    $('body').css('background', 'beige');
  } else if ( i === 2 ) {
    $('body').css('background', 'honeydew');
  } else {
    $('body').css('background', 'pink');
  }

});
```

Comment: you are so on but what if I have 8 options?

Comment: add just add in else if's for each case?

Comment: can it be `else {` cases for the next 5 or `else if {`

Comment: if you have a lot of menu items - name your BG images with according suffix ( e.g. `bg-image-0`, `bg-image-1` etc. ) and then you can use - http://jsfiddle.net/rGFzJ/2/

Comment: don't understand can't I just replace the color with a url

Comment: I was able to do the if statements but how can I change the color to image url

Answer (score 0):

Does this seem about like what you're trying to do?

```
$(".menu-item a:nth-child(1)").click(function () { // first menu item
    $(body).css('background', 'http://example.com/image.png');
});
$(".menu-item a:nth-child(2)").click(function () { // second menu item
    $(body).css('background', 'http://example.com/image.png');
});
$(".menu-item a:nth-child(3)").click(function () { // third menu item
    $(body).css('background', 'http://example.com/image.png');
});
```

Comment: can you test it out on jsfiddle?

Comment: can you do that? this is your question after all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying but I could give you hints.

```
$(".menu-item a") // is an array/jquery collection of all elements that match the selector
    .click(function () { // binds the function now to the click event of every item found
        $(this); // is now the currently clicked element
        // you can now traversal with $(this) for example
        $(this).siblings(); // will be a collection of all surrounding elements
        $(this).next(); // is the next element after the current one, can be chained like:
        $(this).next().next(); // but I wouldn't recomand
        $(this).prev(); // same as next but prev
        $(this).parent(); // selects the direct parent element, in your case the li element
        $(this).children(); // would select the direct children of the current element
        // and so on.... there are much more possibilities
        // on every of this possibilities you can do your background change
        $("some selector"); // is of course still possible

        // i think you are trying to do this:
        var menuItems = $(".menu-item a");
        menuItems.eq(0).css("background", "url to bg 1");
        menuItems.eq(1).css("background", "url to bg 2");
        menuItems.eq(2).css("background", "url to bg 3");
    })
```

Look at the [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) section of the jQuery docu. I would also always recommend to look what jQuery is actually doing. Many people hide behind jQuerys api and have no idea whats happening. This results into many misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

HTML:

```
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a name="blue" href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a name="red" href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a name="orange" href="#">item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
  .red {
    background:red;
  }
  .blue {
     background:blue;
  }
  .orange {
    background:orange;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
  var bgColor = $(this).attr('name');
   $('body').removeClass().addClass(bgColor);
   return false;
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NGH9r/26/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I suggest going about this is to grab the position of the element that has been clicked. You can do this by using jQuery's index() function as other posters have suggested. Remember this will give you a zero-based index of the position which means that the position counting starts at 0 as opposed to 1.

Based on the item that has been clicked, you assign a CSS class to the target item which is the body element based on the sample code you provided.

Also, I noticed that your JS comments are still invalid even they were edited. Single line comments in JS use a double forward slash, `//` whereas multiline comments begin with `/*` and are closed by `*/`.

This is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tgZUK/.